# How to configure TbRelationalColumn with Yii Booster?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I want to implement the extendgridview from yii booster to show the related id from the other table when i click on the table row (TbRelationalColumn).

The documentation frovided on the web site is not sufficent for me to understand how to configure the controler and the model. http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView#extendedgridview

I have 2 tables: 1 Tours and 1 toursdetails. 
The pk in table tours is tour_id and the FK in toursdetails is tour_id 
in my model in tours details i have

```
  public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
            return array(
                  'tours' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'tours', 'tour_id'),

            );
        }
```

in my  tours controller i have

```
   $criteria = 'guide_id=' . Yii::app()->user->id;
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Toursextra', array(
    'criteria' => array(
        'condition' => $criteria,
        'order' => 'date ASC',
    ),
));




  public function actionRelational()
{
    // partially rendering "_relational" view
    $this->renderPartial('_relational', array(
        'id' => Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id'),
        'gridDataProvider' => $this->getGridDataProvider(),
        'gridColumns' => $this->getGridColumns()
    ));
}
```

in the view i have

```
    $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'template' => "{items}",
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'class'=>'booster.widgets.TbRelationalColumn',
            'name' => 'count',
            'url' => $this->createUrl('tours/relational'),
            'value'=> '"test-subgrid"',

        )
    ),
));
```

in the view tours/relational i have

```
<?php

echo CHtml::tag('h3',array(),'RELATIONAL DATA EXAMPLE ROW : "'.$id.'"');
$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'template' => "{items}",
    'columns' => 'money',
));
```

when i implement the solution i get an error , i dont understand how this works , where and how do you set a PK, or i dont know  ,, why do i get an error, if you guys need more details please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In your view tours/relational you call $dataProvider but it is not in the function actionRelational. Yiibooster writes an error if there's something wrong in the view.